# Перетекание иностранных слов в русский язык

Tags: заимствования

Скажите пожалуйста, допустимо ли **новые** заимствования адаптировать к устоявшимся правилам произношения в русском языке. Смягчать звуки, опускать или округлять (смягчать) неудобочитаемые произношения. К сожалению, примера пока привести не могу, не вспомню.

Comment: @Tango, если Вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом)

Answer (score 4):

По-моему,при заимствовании слово всегда подчиняется произносительным нормам русского языка
 http://chisto-po-russki.ru/literaturnoe-proiznoshenie/osobennosti-proiznosheniya-v-russkom-ya

http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=13e90da0-5cb2-4d56-bba8-cda246481d26

Answer (score 3):

> допустимо ли новые заимствования адаптировать...

Все заимствования должны подчиняться законам фонетики русского языка (и вообще языка-мишени). Это общий закон, речь идет **не о допустимости, а об обязательности** такого произношения, которое бы соответствовало правилам русской фонетики. Исключения - имена собственные, особенно топонимы. Но и тут использование чуждой фонетики, во-первых, дело - по счастью - не абсолютное и временное, ибо язык все равно причешет все эти совершенно невозможные (прости, Господи!) **Кы**р**гызс**таны и Талли**нн**ы, а во-вторых, диктуется часто не лингвистикой, а политикой.

ЗЫ Ссылки - см. у Людмилы (при том, что источники совершенно неавторитетны, там правильные вещи  говорятся).

Answer (score 2):

Со временем, почти всегда, адаптация и происходит. "Парикмахер" в речи стал "прихмахером", тем не менее сохранив написание. Не вижу никаких причин заимствовать неудобопроизносимое слово, если оно не является именем собственным, хотя и в этом случае произносится по нормам русской фонетики и изобретать нового звука для dr. Watson'а не стоит.